# Create random filename but check it's not already used

Tags: php, upload

I am trying to upload image files to a server and creating a random name when doing so. The issue I am having is that sometimes (far too often) it creates the same file name but for files with a different extension.

My code for the upload is below, what I want to do is add a check to make sure the name is not in use but with a different extension.

Example -
da4fb5c6e93e74d3df8527599fa62642.jpg & da4fb5c6e93e74d3df8527599fa62642.JPG

```
if ($_FILES['file']['name']) {if (!$_FILES['file']['error']){
$name = md5(mt_rand(100, 200));
$ext = explode('.', $_FILES['file']['name']);
$filename = $name . '.' . $ext[1];
$destination = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/images/infopages/' . $filename; //change this directory
$location = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
move_uploaded_file($location, $destination);
echo '/images/infopages/' . $filename;
}else{
echo  $message = 'Ooops!  Your upload triggered the following error:  '.$_FILES['file']['error'];
}
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: _"...sometimes (far too often) it creates the same file name..."_ - have you though of adding randomness to your algorithm? A range of 100 numbers doesn't allow a lot of wiggle space. You could use UUIDs which guarantee uniqueness on a very large scale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PHP uniqid & rand functions combinedly. In this way you will never get duplicate values.

```
$filename = uniqid (rand(1000000,9999999), true) '.' . $ext[1];
```

Comment: So drop - $name = md5(mt_rand(100, 200)); and replace $filename = $name . '.' . $ext[1]; with $filename = uniqid (rand(1000000,9999999), true) '.' . $ext[1];

Comment: I tried, it wouldn't let me at the time. Have done now though